# Trouble importing Apache HttpComponents into BlueJ, package does not exist

Tags: java, bluej

I'm rewriting a project I made in Ruby into Java (14.0.1) as there is some functionality I would like to add, which I would be much better at in adding in Java. For this project, I'm trying to use Apache HttpComponents (Core & Client 5.0.1) https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi to handle GET and POST requests. I have taken the JARs from the downloaded libs and moved them to my userlibs, e.g. /BlueJ.app/Contents/Resources/Java/userLib/httpclient5-testing-5.0.1.jar then using the libraries menu in preferences I added all the jars from both lib folders so they are "(Loaded)".

When I try to import the libraries so I can use them, e.g.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Authorization
{
    public Authorization()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I get the errors, "package org.apache.http does not exist", "package org.apache.http.client.entity does not exist", etc.

I have tried adding a lib folder in my project folder and importing from there, making sure to restart BlueJ for the changes to take effect, but to no avail. I have tried downloading eclipse and following a tutorial to import the JARs into the project (I forget the details bc I did it a couple days ago), but again to no avail. I know I am doing something wrong and I have spent numerous hours trying my best to troubleshoot but I'm stuck; I've never had to import libraries that weren't included in Java before and I'm gridlocked right now trying to work on a little summer project as I took my first computer science class over this past school year which I really enjoyed.

Thank you!